# Search form with Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, search, codeigniter

I am trying to create a search form in Codeigniter. I want to give the user 4 different options to search from. For the result I want a table that displays all 11 columns in the table I am searching from.  This is the code I have so far.

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->searchTest();
}
public function searchTest(){
    $this->load->model('reg_model');

$search_term = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
    'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'));


    $data['query'] = $this->reg_model->test($search_term);


    $this->load->view("reg_header");
    $this->load->view("reg_nav");
    $this->load->view("reg_search_form", $data);
    $this->load->view("reg_search", $data);
```

Model:

```
public function test($search_term='default'){



   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('voterinfo');
   $this->db->like('firstName', $search_term);
   $this->db->or_like('lastName', $search_term);
   $this->db->or_like('street', $search_term);
   $this->db->or_like('dob', $search_term);
   $query = $this->db->get();


   return $query->result_array();
```

}

View:

```
<?php $this->load->library('table'); foreach ($query as $row){ echo $this->table->generate($row); }?>
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to put in table using codeigniter table class , it should be something like this:

```
$this->load->library('table');

$this->table->set_heading(array('Name', 'Color', 'Size')); //your column name


foreach($query as $row ){
   $this->table->add_row($row);
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

you need also to modify your model. You're query is wrong you forgot the key , it should be like this:

```
public function test($search_term='default'){



   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('voterinfo');
   $this->db->like('firstName', $search_term['firstName']);
   $this->db->or_like('lastName', $search_term['lastName']);
   $this->db->or_like('street', $search_term['street']);
   $this->db->or_like('dob', $search_term['dob']);
   $query = $this->db->get();


   return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: this created the table but I am still unable to get the information from my database from the forms I created.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Another question I have is how would I go about choosing a voter and editing the information in a form

Comment: @medellin81391 that should be in another question :)

Comment: I created a new question here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330770/how-to-select-from-a-table-and-edit-the-information-in-codeigniter