# How to select from a table and Edit the information in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, edit

I am building an application with Codeigniter and in this application I am currently able to search through a database table and generate a table in the application displaying the results. The next step for me is to be able to select a row in the application search result table and redirect me to a form where I can edit the information. I wanted to know how I can do that. below I will give you the code that generates the table.  If more code or information is needed just let me know.

```
foreach ($query as $row){
    $this->table->add_row($row);

}
echo $this->table->generate();
```

**Update**

**Contoller**

```
public function search(){
    $this->load->model('reg_model');

    $search_term = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
    'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob')
        );


    $data['query'] = $this->reg_model->search_voters($search_term);


    $this->load->view("reg_header");
    $this->load->view("reg_nav");
    $this->load->view("reg_search", $data); 
}


public function add(){    

    $this->load->view("reg_header");
    $this->load->view("reg_nav");
    $this->load->view("reg_form"); 
}

public function send(){

    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstName", "First Name", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastName", "Last Name", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("homeNum", "Home Number", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("street", "Street", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("zip", "Zip Code", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("dob", "Date of Birth", 'trim|required|valid_date[d/m/y,/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("district", "District", "required");

    //add to database
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view("reg_header");
        $this->load->view("reg_nav");
        $this->load->view("reg_form");

    }
    else{



        $this->load->model('reg_model');
        $this->reg_model->add_voters();


        redirect(current_url());


    }

    }
    function edit_voterS($voterNum) {
    $voter = $this->reg_model->get_voter($voterNum);

    $this->data['title'] = 'Edit Voter';

    //validate form input
    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstName", "First Name", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastName", "Last Name", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("homeNum", "Home Number", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("street", "Street", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("zip", "Zip Code", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("dob", "Date of Birth", 'trim|required|valid_date[d/m/y,/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("district", "District", "required");

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {       
        $data = array(
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
            'midInitial' => $this->input->post('midInitial'),
            'homeNum' => $this->input->post('homeNum'),
            'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
            'apt' => $this->input->post('apt'),
            'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
            'district' => $this->input->post('district')
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
        {
            $this->reg_model->update_voter($voterNum, $data);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>voter updated successfully.</p>");

            redirect(base_url().'reg/search/'.$voterNum);
        }           
    }

    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

    $this->data['voter'] = $voter;

    //display the edit product form
    $this->data['firstName'] = array(
        'name'      => 'firstName',
        'id'        => 'firstName',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('firstName', $voter['firstName'])
    );

    $this->data['lastName'] = array(
        'name'      => 'lastName',
        'id'        => 'lastName',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('lastName', $voter['lastName'])
    );

    $this->data['midInitial'] = array(
        'name'      => 'midInitial',
        'id'        => 'midInitial',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('midInitial', $voter['firstName'])
        );

    $this->data['homeNum'] = array(
        'name'      => 'homeNum',
        'id'        => 'homeNum',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('homeNum', $voter['homeNum'])
        );


    $this->data['street'] = array(
        'name'      => 'street',
        'id'        => 'street',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('street', $voter['street'])
    );

    $this->data['apt'] = array(
        'name'      => 'apt',
        'id'        => 'apt',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('apt', $voter['apt'])
    );

    $this->data['zip'] = array(
        'name'      => 'zip',
        'id'        => 'zip',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('zip', $voter['zip'])
    );

    $this->data['dob'] = array(
        'name'      => 'dob',
        'id'        => 'dob',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('dob', $voter['dob'])
    );

    $this->data['district'] = array(
        'name'      => 'district',
        'id'        => 'district',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('district', $voter['district'])
    );


    $this->load->view('edit_form', $this->data);
}    
    function delete_voter($voterNum) {
    $this->reg_model->del_voter($voterNum);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p>Product were successfully deleted!</p>');

    redirect('reg/search');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function search_voters($search_term){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('voterinfo');
   $this->db->like('firstName', $search_term['firstName']);
   $this->db->like('lastName', $search_term['lastName']);
   $this->db->like('street', $search_term['street']);
   $this->db->like('dob', $search_term['dob']);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array(); }

public function get_voter($voterNum) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('voterNum', $voterNum);
    $query = $this->db->get('voterinfo');

    return $query->row_array();
}

public function update_voter($voterNum, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('voterNum', $voterNum);
    $this->db->update('voter', $data);
}

public function del_voter($voterNum)
{
    $this->db->where('voterNum', $voterNum);
    $this->db->delete('voter');
}
```

**Search View:**

```
echo form_open("reg/search");

echo form_label("First Name: ", "firstName");

$data = array(
    "name" => "firstName",
    "id" => "firstName",
    "value" => set_value("firstName")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Last Name: ", "lastName");

$data = array(
    "name" => "lastName",
    "id" => "lastName",
    "value" => set_value("lastName")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Street: ", "street");

$data = array(
    "name" => "street",
    "id" => "street",
    "value" => set_value("street")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Date of Birth: ", "dob");

$data = array(
    "name" => "dob",
    "id" => "dob",
    "value" => set_value("dob")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_submit("searchSubmit", "Search");

echo form_close();




$this->table->set_heading(array('', 'Voter Number', 'First Name', 'Last Name',
                                'Middle', 'Home #', 'Street',
                                'Apt', 'Zip', 'DOB',
                                'District', 'Edit'));

foreach ($query as $row){
    $this->table->add_row($row);

}
echo $this->table->generate();
```

**edit form view:**

```
echo validation_errors();
```

echo form_open("reg/edit_voter");
echo form_label("First Name: ", "firstName");

```
$data = array(
    "name" => "firstName",
    "id" => "firstName",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('firstName', $voter['firstName'])
);    
echo form_input($data);


echo form_label("Last Name: ", "lastName");

$data = array(
    "name" => "lastName",
    "id" => "lastName",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('lastName', $voter['lastName'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Middle Initial: ", "midInitial");

$data = array(
    "name" => "midInitial",
    "id" => "midInitial",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('midInitial', $voter['midInitial'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Home Number: ", "homeNum");

$data = array(
    "name" => "homeNum",
    "id" => "homeNum",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('homeNum', $voter['homeNum'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Street: ", "street");

$data = array(
    "name" => "street",
    "id" => "street",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('street', $voter['street'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Apartment Number: ", "apt");

$data = array(
    "name" => "apt",
    "id" => "apt",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('apt', $voter['apt'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Zip Code: ", "zip");

$data = array(
    "name" => "zip",
    "id" => "zip",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('zip', $voter['zip'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Date of Birth: ", "dob");

$data = array(
    "name" => "dob",
    "id" => "dob",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('dob', $voter['dob'])
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("District: ", "district");

$data = array(
    "name" => "district",
    "id" => "district",
    "value" => $this->form_validation->set_value('district', $voter['district'])
);    
echo form_input($data);


echo form_submit("editSubmit", "edit");
echo form_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires two steps.

- the first step is to load the existing data from the result.
- the second step is to update the data you edited

For the first stop you want to create a link/button for each `$row` with the `id` of the result, let it call to a function in the controller with the `id` as parameter( for example `loadEdit($id)`).

let that function make a call to your model you are handling the results in, and send the `id`
with it as its only parameter:

```
public function loadEdit($id){
    $this->load->model('model_results');
    $id = $id;
    $editData = $this->model_results->loadEdit_results($id);
}
```

in the `loadEdit_results` function in your model you only want to get 1 `$row`. The one corresponding with the `id` of the result you want to to edit.
So you write something like this query in that function:

```
public function edit_page($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('pages', array('id' => $id));
}
```

This will get the one result with corresponding `id`.

Now it's time for the next step. The updating part:

I guess you know how to show the results in the view, so i don't go into that.
Just create a form with the data of the result in a form, and let that form submit to the edit function (for exmaple `postEdit($id)`) in your controller (dont forget, use the `id` as the parameter for the function)

the `postEdit($id)` function will have to make a call to your model, and send all the data there:

```
public function edit_page_validation($id){
    $this->load->model('model_pages');          
    $this->model_pages->edit_page_update($id);
}
```

Then create a function in your model to update the result with the corresponding `id`.

```
public function edit_page_update($id){
$data = array(
    /*
    the array with the posted data from the form
    */
);

$query = $this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->update('results', $data);
}
```

This might be a bit much to take in if you've never done something like this before. So here are some links to help you out:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Hopefully i helped you a bit :)

Comment: I amstill having issues. I just updated my post and added functions from my MVC.

Comment: With this post i gave you an idea how you can do it. Study it, and try some things out. What are the issues you are still having now? My examples were not meant to blindly copy/paste :P

Comment: my issue right now is being able to actually select the voter from the table to send me to the edit form.

Comment: You can output a table with the voter info right? So what you have to do is add a button/link to that table, that points to a function, and takes the voters `id` as a parameter. something like: `<a href="/controller/editUser/$id">Edit voter</a>`. I hope you know how to catch those parameters, and use them within the function. then create a function in your model that uses the `id`, returns the value's, and then in your view you create a form with the value's of the voter already filled in. Then you can edit those fields, `POST` it, and use a `update` query. Hopefully this makes some sense.